# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE }

Tags: android, android-intent

I received the following crash report in my Android application when trying to call the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent.  This code has been running in my app for months with no issues.  I am guessing this is something specific to a certain type of phone but unfortunately Google does not provide me with any additional information outside the stack trace.  Any ideas what could have caused this crash report?

**Stack Trace**

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromChild(Activity.java:3067)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2847)
```

**Producing Code**

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, MY_CAMERA_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

**Manifest Entries**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few things come to mind
1.Could be a tablet, the kindle fire does not have a camera.
2. A phone that does not have a camera
3. No SD card installed

I agree you would think it would be a safe operation to call the image capture intent but with so many devices running Android it's impossible to know what device your app is running on.

Comment: Thanks.  I misunderstood the purpose of "uses-feature", thinking the Android Market would filter out my application if the device did not have a camera.  "Declared <uses-feature> elements are informational only, meaning that the Android system itself does not check for matching feature support on the device before installing an application."  I found another post with an example on how to perform a check to see if the camera exists.  I will end up implementing something like this and display a message to the user if their device does not have a camera.

Comment: Get the same error, but have an emulated device with camera and sdcard. It's also not a tablet. Get the error on devices with API 7 & 8. Any tips?