# Application get crashed while I am trying to open Camera in android 7.0

Tags: java, android

In my application there is a facility to capture image by using Camera.
Its working perfectly for all the versions until Android 6,But it make my app crashed in Android version 7.0.

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Permission added

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(AddFamilyMemberActivity.this,
                android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AddFamilyMemberActivity.this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    1);
        } else {
            sendToExternalApp();
        }
```

Permission Listener

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 1 && permissions[0].equals(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) &&
                grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            sendToExternalApp();
        } else if (requestCode == 1 && permissions[0].equals(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) &&
                grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            Utilities.showSnackBar("You need to enable camera permission for update profile image", this);
        }
    }
```

Code to open camera

```
protected void sendToExternalApp()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        mProcessingPhotoUri =  getImageFile();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mProcessingPhotoUri);
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_IMAGE);
    }
```

Crash log

Caused by: 
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 clip={text/uri-list U:file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/QDhealth/profile.jpg} (has extras) }

Comment: Are you sure the permissions are also put into your manifest

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question with manifest permission

Comment: where is your log?

Comment: I have updated it in the qusetion

Comment: did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15565539/5545429)?

Comment: What you are saying about

Comment: 1) there might not be any camera in the device
2) there is no sd card in the device

Comment: @JITHINRAJ Its possible duplicate. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026085/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-act-android-media-action-image-capture

Comment: The device have default camera, Is there any issue if there is no sd card in the device.  I am using moto g4 plus

Comment: What is this device? Apparently, it lacks an app that supports `android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first screen check the permisson given as below

onCreate (or) initialize

```
if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}
```

Overide below method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length <= 0 || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            break;
    }
}
```